# how to append two tables into one in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking for a way to append two tables in postgresql

table_1 is like

```
name | age | grade
aaa    20    A
bbb    21    B
```

And table_2 is like

```
name | age | grade
ccc    20     C
ddd    22     A
```

What i am trying to do is append table_2 to table_1, so that table_1 will be

```
name | age | grade
aaa     20   A
bbb     21   B
ccc     20   C
ddd     22   A
```

Done these things. Like create a "sample.sql" file and try to run

```
database_name=# \i /path/to/sample.sql
```

It resulted in error. The statements in sample.sql file is

```
select * from table_1
union
select * from table_2
insert into table_1;
```

I am new to the database thing.

Comment: Do it in the opposite order, and do not insert table_1 into table_1 again: `insert into table_1 select * from table_2;` http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
insert into table_1 (name, age, grade)
select name, age, grade
from table_2;
```